# Can I install 2TB HDD on a Toshiba Satellite L845 Laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite L845 Laptop with an Intel Core i3-2350M processor.
I have installed a 1TB HDD and it currently runs 64-bit Windows 7.
My BIOS version is Insyde Corp. 1.00.
Is it possible to upgrade to a 2TB HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is fairly new, why would you think it wouldn't work? As long as the interface is the same (most all laptop computers in the last 6+ years use a SATA interface) the likely hood you will run into a BIOS/UEFI limit on HD size in modern computers is near zero.

That being said, any drive up to 2.2TB should be a drop in replacement with no changes to the system, just reinstall or us a utility like [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) to move your data and resize the partitions all in one operation, and away you go. If you are moving to larger volume sizes like a 4TB drive, you will have to use GUID/GPT style partitioning which could pose a few differences, but since you are looking at a 2TB drive this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was told that secod generation processors(2350M), and the BIOS that they come with were not able no support 2TB HDD, but I had my doubts.

Comment: @DavidEspinoza I can tell you that is not an issue... I have a much older Toshiba with a Core 2 Duo and 2TB drive installed, works fine. Although you may want to look here for a BIOS update, there are MULTIPLE newer ones: http://support.toshiba.com/sscontent?contentId=4001722 Just make sure you have the correct model of laptop.